# Android retrieve values from sql table into listview

Tags: android, sql, listview

Question is based on [this](http://www.devx.com/wireless/Article/40842/1954) tutorial.

I have to java classes:

- DBAdapter.java: this is the helper class that uses the database.
- DatabaseActivity.java: where i am adding rows to the db, retrieving
  values etc.

In the DBAdapter class this is the function to retrieve all values from a table:

```
public Cursor getAllTitles()
{
return db.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {
KEY_ROWID, KEY_ISBN, KEY_TITLE, KEY_PUBLISHER}, null, null, null, null, null);
}
```

In the DatabaseActivity class this is how I retrieve all values:

```
Cursor c = db.getAllTitles();
if (c.moveToFirst())
{
 do {
     DisplayTitle(c);
    } while (c.moveToNext());
}
```

This is the function outside the onCreate() method:

```
   public void DisplayTitle(Cursor c)
    {
    Toast.makeText(this,
    "id: " + c.getString(0) + "\n" +
    "ISBN: " + c.getString(1) + "\n" +
    "TITLE: " + c.getString(2) + "\n" +
    "PUBLISHER: " + c.getString(3),
    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

In main.xml I have a listview.

This is the dblist.xml which has the layout of that listview:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:orientation="horizontal">
     <TextView android:id="@+id/ISBN"
         android:layout_width="200dip"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
     <TextView android:id="@+id/TITLE"
         android:layout_width="30dip"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1"/>
     <TextView android:id="@+id/PUBLISHER"
         android:layout_width="30dip"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"  android:layout_weight="1"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

I want to put the values of the table (3 columns) into this listview. How should I do that?

Comment: this sample looks good http://kahdev.wordpress.com/2010/09/27/android-using-the-sqlite-database-with-listview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need an Adapter for your ListView which sets the right data for each row in your database. If you're working with Cursors you should think about a [CursorAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CursorAdapter.html) and use it's bindView-method to set the right data.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend a `SimpleCursorAdapter` (documentation [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleCursorAdapter.html)). [This](http://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/01/09/simplecursoradapters-and-listviews/) is a great tutorial that will get you going. As the title "Simple" suggests, this is a great way to bind your database data to a list and refresh it easily without a ton of customizing work. Good luck.